# Need I use ng-hide/ng-show in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an table in HTML with some rows that content information about users.
I can click on each rows.

So, i would like to know must I use `ng-hide/ng-show`? Is it right way or exists more well solutions in Angular JS?

I mean:

```
<div class="table" ng-show="details == false">
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>

<div class="tableDetails" ng-show="details == true">
  <div class="row">Name</div>
  <div class="row">Post code</div>
</div>
```

When I click on `<div class="row"></div>` from `class="table"` then this table is hidden and is shown table `class="tableDetails"`. When is loaded table 2, how I can display table 1 when I click button `come back`?

Comment: What about use ng-class with a logic and display:none, I guess it is another option

Comment: numerous ways to do it ..another is `ng-if` also don't need to use `==` for booleans ....  for false can use `ng-show="!details"`

Answer (score 1):

you can use these ways: `ng-class` | `ng-(show|hide)` | `ng-if`

```
<div class="table" ng-if="!details">
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>

<div class="tableDetails" ng-if="details">
  <div class="row">Name</div>
  <div class="row">Post code</div>
</div>
```